# only select the rows with different value

Tags: sql, sas

I want to select two rows with different value

```
Obs  x   y   z
1   23  49  16
2   23  16  83
3   49  16  83
4   23  49  83
5   23  83  75
6   49  83  75
7   16  83  75
8   23  16  75
9   49  16  75
10  23  49  75
11  23  75  42
12  49  75  42
13  16  75  42
14  83  75  42
15  23  83  42
16  49  83  42
17  16  83  42
18  23  16  42
19  49  16  42
20  23  49  42
```

The Table name is called MyData, it is a 20*3 table. If you watch the rows carefully, you will always find two rows with distinct value...I want them both out and make a new 10*6 table.

For instance

23 49 16 should combine with 83 75 42

23 16 83 should combine with 49 75 42

...

Final table should look like:( 10*6 table)

a  b   c  d  e  f

23 49 16 83 75 42

23 16 83 49 75 42
...

Comment: Can you do a better job of explaining what you are trying to do?

Comment: The Table name is called MyData. If you watch the rows carefully, you will always find two rows with distinct value...I want them both out

Comment: There are some issues with this requirement. For instance, have you considered that there may be multiple solutions? And what if there is no solution? Should it do as best as possible or return nothing at all?

Comment: In any case, it seems like you are solving a puzzle and I don't think SQL is the right approach to solve it. With an imperative language like Python solving this should be a breeze.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a selfjoin with all rows that have different values for all columns:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab t1
JOIN tab t2
ON t1.x NOT IN (t2.x,t2.y,t2.z)
AND t1.y NOT IN (t2.x,t2.y,t2.z)
AND t1.z NOT IN (t2.x,t2.y,t2.z)
```

Comment: what is the tab t1 and tab t2?

Comment: table t1 and table t2. in your case its myData t1 and myData t2